# MacBook drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, macbook

I have a hard drive which I removed from my HP Laptop and plugged into my Macbook. Windows 7 started well and then installed a graphics driver but the others (sound, touchpad) were not recognized by the operating system.

What should I do?

I have a Tiger CD but problem is neither my MacBook, nor my desktop PC can read the CD. I have downloaded [drivers from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL74) but it's not working. I mean, when I double click the exe file, it gets listed in process list in the Task Manager but after five seconds, it disappears.

Somehow, Windows recognized my audio device and installed its driver. The microphone is okay but the red light is on.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6), it sounds like the Windows drivers are on the Snow Leopard install disc.  [See this post on apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986).

Answer (score 1):

If you look on your OSX DVD there are windows drivers on there somewhere as I recall, they might be in the Bootcamp assistant app though and not actually visible to you directly.

Aside from that you might be able to find them online somewhere, If you can figure out what make/model the components that aren't working right are, you should be able to find the drivers on the manufacturers website.

Comment: No, they're directly on the CD. Windows will find them without having to use Boot Camp Assistant. I've never used the assistant because it balks at my complex partitioning schemes, and I've never had any trouble installing the drivers in Windows once I finish the install.